# AWS API Gateway don't populate method request in transformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

We are using AWS API Gateway, which provide HTTP endpoint with POST method which we can to call like on this image:
[image]

This Gateway call our AWS Lambda function using Lambda Proxy integration. The issue is that input object, which we pass to function handler, came with not populated fields when we make call to Gateway from external REST client. If try to call Gateway in test mode (from AWS Gateway console page) with the same headers and body we see that Lambda handler get correctly populated request object. There are some details from logs below.

Log records on method request **before transformation** in test-mode call:

```
Execution log for request test-request
Wed Aug 30 16:05:02 UTC 2017 : Starting execution for request: test-invoke-request
Wed Aug 30 16:05:02 UTC 2017 : HTTP Method: POST, Resource Path: /member/alert/tmv/style
Wed Aug 30 16:05:02 UTC 2017 : Method request path: {}
Wed Aug 30 16:05:02 UTC 2017 : Method request query string: {}
Wed Aug 30 16:05:02 UTC 2017 : Method request headers: {authorization=************************************g8_A5Q}
Wed Aug 30 16:05:02 UTC 2017 : Method request body before transformations: { "styleId": "401630051" }
```

Log records related to method request body in test-mode call **after transformation**:

```
Wed Aug 30 16:05:02 UTC 2017 : Endpoint request body after transformations: {"resource":"/member/alert/tmv/style","path":"/member/alert/tmv/style","httpMethod":"POST","headers":{"authorization":"************************************g8_A5Q [TRUNCATED]
```

As you can see after transformation request body contains populated fields like resource, path, headers, etc. That's correct behavior. But when I call API Gateway not from AWS Console, but from my HTTP client I see in logs that request fields are empty. Any ideas why can this happens?

Comment: Are you using a request mapping template?

Comment: @dashmug, no we don't use mapping templates